# Declaring a local variable as const

Tags: c#, constants

Clearly, declaring a local variable as `const`, prevents runtime modification. `Const` instance variables are static (I believe). Does this have any bearing on the nature and use of `const` local variables? (e.g. threading)

Comment: You would do well to read section 10.4 of the C# specification if you want the definitive characterization of constant fields. There seems to be a fair amount of misinformation and whatnot in the various answers here.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A `const` is not a variable, that's why it's called a constant.

Comment: From Wikipedia "a constant is a special kind of variable". http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_(programming). Apologies for the lazy use of terms in OQ.

Comment: A const is not a variable in its original meaning (i.e. its not variable, but constant). However I'm pretty sure a 'const int' can be called a const variable.

Comment: @Ben: Wikipedia is wrong so far as C# is concerned. In C# a constant is not any kind of variable. A variable is defined in C# as a storage location whose contents can vary. A constant is neither a storage location, nor can it vary.

Answer (score 17):

"const" variables have to have a primitive type (e.g. int, bool). Whenever a "const" variable appears in the source code (whether it's local or global), this instance is replaced with the const value itself. So:

```
const int foo = 42;
return foo + 69;
```

after optimizing becomes:

```
return 42 + 69
```

or rather:

```
return 111;
```

There are no threading issues because const variables have primitive types and they only exist at compile time.

Comment: There are a number of errors in this answer. First off, "const variable" is an oxymoron; constants are never variables because variables are *storage locations* that contain a value that can change, and constants are *values* (not storage locations) that *cannot* change.

Comment: Second, constants are not required to be of "primitive" type. Constants can be of any built-in value type (int, short, etc), or any string constant, or a null reference of any reference type.

Comment: Third, I don't understand what being of primitive type or being known at compile time has to do with threading. Constants are not threadsafe "because they are of primitive type". Constants are threadsafe *because by definition they cannot change* and therefore are never observed to have inconsistent values on two different threads.

Comment: @EricLippert I think the same, but I'd like to point out that I think what sthalik meant with "they only exist at compile time" was the fact that const names are optimized away and made indistinguishable from "literal" values during the compilation step.

Answer (score 14):

A constant is not a variable, and it isn't actually stored anywhere. As it isn't stored, it's not an instance member, and it's not static.

The constant is just a name for a value. When the code is compiled the value is inserted where the constant is used. (This has implications if you use a constant declared in a different assembly. Changing the declared value of the constant doesn't change the value used until you recompile the code that uses the constant.)

So, a constant declared locally works exactly as a constant declared anywhere else, it's only the scope that differs.

Comment: To clarify - the places where I have seen const's referred to as static are incorrect?

Comment: @Ben: Yes, constants are not static. A static variable has static storage, while a constant has no storage at all.

Comment: @Ben, @Guffa. No, that isn't quite right. Just because a constant does not have an associated storage location does not imply that it is not a member! A constant field *is* a member of its declaring type, and in fact it is a *static* member.

Comment: @Eric: Yes, you are right that constants are classified as static members (for some reason), but they are not stored statically, which is the important point for this question.

Answer (score 4):

I need to chime in to say that I feel the consensus answers already given are not complete.

Taking the liberty to summarize those answers, the consensus is that we should consider the following code to NOT BE a variable declaration, but rather a kind of macro declaration where the compiler inlines the const value wherever the identifier is used:

```
const int foo = 42;
```

However, that answer sidesteps the questions that arise if the const "variable" is declared using a (possibly complex) constant expression, such as the following:

```
const double H = 1.23e-2, Q = 7.65e-4, nu = 0.3;
const double Reynolds = H*H*H*H / Q / (1d - nu);
```

In such a case, it makes a difference whether the compiler evaluates the expression once and 'stores' the result for re-use (like a static variable), or if it executes the expression each time the identifier is used (like a #define macro in C/C++).

In my own poking around, I found the following description in http://www.techopedia.com/definition/3768/constant-c that speaks to this issue:

> In the context of C#, a constant is a type of field or local variable whose value is set at compile time and can never be changed at run time. It is similar to a variable by having a name, a value, and a memory location. However, it differs from the variable by its characteristic of getting initialized only once in the application. A constant is declared using the keyword "const".

Admittedly, the "memory location" part is kind of a stretch -- I take it to mean that the const value is stored somewhere locally during compilation.  As mentioned elsewhere, you can't ever access or reference this memory in your code.  Otherwise, this appears to be consistent with what I read in the C# Language specification:

> ### 8.5.2 Local constant declarations
>
> A *local-constant-declaration* declares one or more local constants.
>
> *local-constant-declaration:*
>
> > const  type  *{constant-declarators ,} constant-declarator*
>
> *constant-declarator:*
>
> > *identifier  =  constant-expression*

And:

> ### 7.19 Constant expressions
>
> A *constant-expression* is an expression that can be fully evaluated at compile-time.
>
> *constant-expression:*
>
> > *expression*
>
> ...
>
> Whenever an expression fulfills the requirements listed above, the expression is evaluated at compile-time. This is true even if the expression is a sub-expression of a larger expression that contains non-constant constructs.

Any feedback on this "quanser" is welcome :^)

Comment: Interestingly enough, the C# compiler is actually allowed to evaluate operations on constants at compile time, so even if `const` did what a C++ macro would do and drop the entire uncomputed expression everywhere in code, each of those separate expressions would be computed *at compile time* into a single constant value.  Doing the computation once before plopping the value in everywhere its used would speed up the *compilation* time (which I'm sure it'd do) but it would have no effect on the execution speed of the program.

Comment: of course you can access it.  You read the variable value.

Answer (score 3):

Since every method call creates its own stack area and therefore owns its own local variables, you won't need to worry about locals beeing modified from other threads.

AFAIK creating locals as const in c# won't create any variable or field at all, but instead the assigned constant value will be placed inline everywhere you use it inside the method.

Answer (score 2):

The main advantage of locally using `const` is so you don't accidentaly set the identifier to another value which may change the correctness of your code.

Answer (score -3):

I posted this also to [Why can't I declare a constant using var in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6132412/why-cant-i-declare-a-constant-using-var-in-c)

Constants without var:

```
const int Value1 = 1;
const int Value2 = 2;
```

Constants with var (anonymous type property values cannot be changed after creation):

```
var constants = new { 
  Value1 = 1, 
  Value2 = 2,
};
//use as constants.Value1
```

Comment: The object you have created cannot be mutated, but the variable you put it in *can* be mutated to point to another object entirely, making this not the same at all to a constant field.