# Why can't I declare a constant using var in C#?

Tags: c#, declaration, implicit-declaration

this:

```
const int a = 5;
```

compiles just fine, whereas

```
const var a = 5;
```

doesn't... while:

```
var a = 5;
```

compiles just as well as this:

```
int a = 5;
```

**why?**

Comment: Let me see if I get the this straight... You want to know "Why you can't **dynamically** type and **constant** value?"... maybe because it if don't know what type it is, the last thing you want do is make it constant?

Comment: How about this? `const` is shorthand for "constant"; `var` is shorthand for "variable". Constants and variables are polar opposites, making `const var` an oxymoron.

Comment: @Cos var doesn't dynamically type. It just tells the compiler "hey, figure this variables type out yourself."

Comment: Then what of your definition of "dynamic" that doesn't include "figure it out yourself"?

Comment: @Cos Callis: variables declared with `var` are **statically** typed using type-inference (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_inference) at compile time.

Comment: Hm, but if memory serves me right, in C++, where you have the "auto" keyword for essentially the same purpose, you can make it const. And why shouldn't you ?constness has nothing to do with the type it represents. It's just there to tell us, that the intent for the usage of this bit of memory is to remain unchanged.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `var` keyword was intended to save you from writing long complex typenames, which cannot be constants.

It is very convenient to be able to write declarations like

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, List<Definition>>();
```

It becomes *necessary* when using anonymous types.

For constants, this isn't an issue.
The longest built-in typename with constant literals is `decimal`; that's not a very long name.

It is possible to have arbitrarily long `enum` names which can be used as constants, but the C# compiler team apparently wasn't concerned for that.
For one thing, if you're making a constant `enum` value, you might as well put it in the `enum`.
Also, `enum` names shouldn't be too long.  (Unlike complex generic types, which can and frequently should)

Comment: So, in summary, 'just because'?

Comment: @Michael - I see this answer explains why you might not really *need* to use `var` for constants, but it doesn't explain why you *can't*.

Comment: @Kirk - One implies the other, or at least should - if something's not really useful, it shouldn't be done. Eric Gunnerson  explains it with [different words](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericgu/archive/2004/01/12/57985.aspx): *every feature starts off with negative 100 points*.

Comment: @Michael - Good point, I like that explanation.

Comment: Yes `const var` is dumb, but if `var` is a convenience, then `const` should be able to do the same thing:  `const s = "mystring"`.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/2614617/1037948

Comment: var isn't just about brevity and convenience. It's also about redundancy. Writing the type twice is against the DRY (don't repeat yourself) principle.

Comment: It is wrong to say that type inference on constants is pointless or useless. It may be a limitation by C#, but it would be useful. Apple's programming language Swift has type inference for constants and it makes perfect sense there.

Comment: In C++11 you can say, e.g. `const auto i = 5`. It's not pointless or useless with more complex types. There's no reason why it couldn't work also in C# with `var`.

Answer (score 9):

It is a compiler limitation, and the reason for that limitation is given by Eric Lippert [here](https://ericlippert.com/2009/01/26/why-no-var-on-fields)

Comment: Eric lippert has left a comment to this question which might be more definitive: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128432/type-inferring-a-constant-in-c

Answer (score 2):

Constants without var:

```
const int Value1 = 1;
const int Value2 = 2;
```

Constants with var (anonymous type property values cannot be changed after creation):

```
var constants = new { 
  Value1 = 1, 
  Value2 = 2,
};
//use as constants.Value1
```

Answer (score 0):

Since constants must be built-in numeric types or `string`, you don't really save much; `const int` is the same length as `const var` and `int` is probably the most common type of constant. Then there's `double` which is really not all that long. If you have a lot of them to type, use the Alt selection feature ;-)